# How to get UTC timestamp of a specific hour?

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, foundation

I get the current UTC timestamp using Timezone(abbreviation:"UTC") but can't get the UTC timestamp of some other timestamp.

```
/*Current local time (4:15 PM) ---> Current UTC (11:15 AM)
Some other time    (11:15 PM)  ---> UTC (6:15 PM)*/

static func getDateFormat(by date:Date, format:String) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        formatter.locale = Locale.current
        return formatter.string(from: date)
    }
```

This always give the current UTC.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. This code will return the value of the supplied date expressed in the UTC timezone. What output do you expect? Note that a `Date` is a specific point in time.  It does not have a timezone. Can you show how you are creating the `Date` instances that you are passing to this function?

Comment: Following up on Paul's questions, can you provide an example of the calling code, showing what it does return, and what you wish it would return?

Answer (score 1):

```
func convertToUTC(dateToConvert:String) -> String {

     let formatter = DateFormatter()
     formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"
     let convertedDate = formatter.date(from: dateToConvert)
     formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
     return formatter.string(from: convertedDate!)

}
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to the author of the question and to future readers of this thread) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting code only.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not explained properly, though i got your question after reading it multiple times.
You want a function in which you provide a date and that function return you a new date in UTC format.

```
func convertDateToUTC(date: Date) -> Date {
  let calendar = Calendar.current
  let dateComponent = calendar.dateComponents([.timeZone], from: date)
  //get difference of curent time zone from gmt
  //subtract 0 as we want UTC from current time zone
  let gmtDiff = 0-dateComponent.timeZone!.secondsFromGMT()

  let dateStr = "11:15 PM"
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
  let date1 = formatter.date(from: dateStr)
  let newDate = date1?.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(gmtDiff))
  return newDate
}
```

You can format method as your convenience. 
We need date components to get time zone difference of current to UTC, then we add that seconds to date and new date we get will be UTC date  .

Comment: Please do not do this. A Date is a specific instant in time, unrelated to time zones, or calendars, or even "hours and minutes." Adding `secondsFromGMT` creates a new instant in time that is not "in UTC." It's just a completely different instant in time.